# How should I make a bool thread safe for this example of a web service constructor that does auto login?

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services, thread-safety

I believe I've successfully implemented a "spin lock" here, but I wanted to investigate the best practice for something like this.

Should I be using the Interlocked class?  If so, which method is appropriate for a bool value type?  Otherwise, what it the right way to accomplish this (if my way is not already)?

```
// This is a class to encapsulate a bool value that can be used
// as a signal from one thread to another.
public class Condition
{
    private object locker = new object();
    private bool isDone;

    public void Wait()
    {
        while (true) if (!this.Done) Thread.Sleep(100); else break;
    }

    public void Set()
    {
        this.Done = true;
    }

    private bool Done
    {
        get { lock (this.locker) { return this.isDone; } }
        set { lock (this.locker) { this.isDone = value; } }
    }
}

// This is an extension to a WSDL generated web service.
// The idea is to login to the web service as part of instance construction.
public partial class SforceService
{
    private Condition done = new Condition();

    public SforceService(string login, string password)
        : this()
    {
        this.loginCompleted += new loginCompletedEventHandler(SforceService_loginCompleted);
        this.loginAsync(login, password);
        this.done.Wait();
    }

    void SforceService_loginCompleted(object sender, loginCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var loginResult = e.Result;
        this.SessionHeaderValue = new SessionHeader();
        this.Url = loginResult.serverUrl;
        this.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = loginResult.sessionId;
        this.done.Set();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are trying to reimplement a [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx).

Take a look at the Set() and WaitOne() methods, they may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Doing multithreaded code? First, check up on what synchro primitives/objects are available on your OS/language.